# How to retrieve data if not exist with certain condition in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 3 values

1. SecurityLevel - ex:1
2. ReportName    - ex:'TotalSales'
3. UserID        - ex:'faisal.3012'

I have 2 tables:

1. `SecurityLevelDetails`
2. `SecurityUserDetails`

I want to check the data whether it is already exists or not in `SecurityUserDetails`. If exist, I want to retrieve that exist record, if not I want to retrieve record from `SecurityLevelDetails`.

I try to make it as a single query, I can do using if condition. But I don't want to do.

I tried this. I know this is wrong.

```
Select 
    ReportHide, RColumnName, RFilterName
From 
    HQWebMatajer.dbo.SecurityLevelDetails sld
Where 
    SecurityLevel = 1 
    and not exists(select top 1 
                       UserID, ReportHide, RColumnName, RFilterName 
                   from 
                       [HQWebMatajer].[dbo].[SecurityUserDetails] 
                   where 
                       [UserID] = 'faisal.3012' 
                       and [ReportName] = 'TotalSales')
```

It's retrieving a record if it does not exist in `SecurityUserDetails`. But I want to retrieve the record from `SecurityUserDetails` if it exists

**UPDATED**
I got the result from below code. But I am trying to make in single query

```
declare @flags int = 0;
select top 1 @flags=count(*)
from [HQWebMatajer].[dbo].[SecurityUserDetails] 
where [UserID]='faisal.3012' and [ReportName]='TotalSales';

if(@flags>0)
BEGIN
    select top 1 UserID,ReportHide,RColumnName,RFilterName 
    from [HQWebMatajer].[dbo].[SecurityUserDetails] 
    where [UserID]='faisal.3012' and [ReportName]='TotalSales'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    select SecurityLevel,ReportHide,RColumnName,RFilterName
    From HQWebMatajer.dbo.SecurityLevelDetails sld
    where SecurityLevel=1 and ReportName='TotalSales'
END
```

Comment: @marc_s are you happy now?. ;)

Comment: The question is definitely **more readable** and thus **more approachable** for anyone who might be interested in it, and might be able to help you ....

Comment: If it exists in neither do you want no records? What is the join column(s) between the tables? is the relationship 1-1?

Comment: @marc_s makes questions readable. I just ask questions until you actually explain everything required.

Comment: Side note: the query inside the `not exists()` clause really doesn't have to specify any columns - none of those will be returned. You can just as well use `select *` - the `EXISTS` clause **only** checks if at least one row for the given criteria in the `WHERE` clause exists - and only returns a "yes" or "no"

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Sometimes it may have records on both table. But I don't want to retrieve from both. If there is no records on both, then I don't need any record

Comment: I don't know how you find one that doesn't match the other, because we don't know what fields are used to join between the tables. You need to specify that or no one can help

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid my criteria is very sample. Don't make it complete. If record exists on **SecurityUserDetails**, then I need that record, If not I need record from **SecurityLevelDetails** `where SecurityLevel=1 and ReportName='TotalSales'`. that's all

Comment: One way to approach this is with `UNION ALL`. The general form is `SELECT C1,C2 FROM SecurityUserDetails WHERE C5='A' UNION ALL SELECT C1,C2 FROM SecurityLevelDetails WHERE C5='A' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  SecurityUserDetails ....)`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid That should be posted as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this is with `UNION ALL`

You have both sides defined and a UNION ALL joins them up

I'll stick together all of the code you have posted so far:

```
select top 1 UserID,ReportHide,RColumnName,RFilterName 
from [HQWebMatajer].[dbo].[SecurityUserDetails] 
where [UserID]='faisal.3012' and [ReportName]='TotalSales'
UNION ALL
select SecurityLevel,ReportHide,RColumnName,RFilterName
From HQWebMatajer.dbo.SecurityLevelDetails sld
where SecurityLevel=1 
and ReportName='TotalSales'
and not exists(select *
               from 
                   [HQWebMatajer].[dbo].[SecurityUserDetails] 
               where 
                   [UserID] = 'faisal.3012' 
                   and [ReportName] = 'TotalSales')
```